# Bray-Curtis Dissimilarity in R

Tags: r

Sorry that I am a new learner in R. It may be a little bit silly and confused.

If I have a dataset like:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(4, 3,4,5),
                 B=c(0, 6,6,4),
                 C=c(2, 0,3,2),
                 D=c(7, 4,2,1),
                 E=c(8, 11,10,8))
```

To culculate the Bray-Curtis Dissimilarity, I am trying to use the below code like:

```
sum(apply(df, 2, function(x) abs(max(x)-min(x)))) / sum(rowSums(df))
```

However, I am wondering what should I do if I wanna calculate the Bray-Curtis Dissimilarity between samples A and B/ samples A and D/ A, B and C only.

In fact, I have more than 100 samples, how could I keep looping this pattern?

Thanks a lot for your guy's help!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use either `bcdist()` in package `ecodist` or `vegdist()` in package `vegan`. Install each of the packages and then:

```
library(vegan)
library(ecodist)
vegdist(df, method="bray")     # Package vegan
#           1         2         3
# 2 0.3333333                    
# 3 0.3043478 0.1428571          
# 4 0.2682927 0.2727273 0.1555556
bcdist(df)      # Package ecodist
#           1         2         3
# 2 0.3333333                    
# 3 0.3043478 0.1428571          
# 4 0.2682927 0.2727273 0.1555556
```